# A specific nestjs controller method is returning empty response

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a controller method in my nest controller file, but when I hit the endpoint, it's giving me empty/blank response.

This is the method:

```
@Get('/practice')
  async practice() {
    const event = await this.repository.findOneBy({
      id: 3
    })

    return event;
  }
```

Even if I try to return a string instead of `event`, the response is still blank.

However, other methods in controller are returning appropriate responses. For example, this method is returning the right response.

```
@Get(':id')
  async findOne(@Param('id') id) {
    const event = await this.repository.findOneBy({
      id: id
    })

    return event;
  }
```

I'm unable to understand what's causing this issue. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.

I defined the `/practice` route after the `:id` route. Changing the order resolved the issue.

```
@Get('/practice')
  async practice() {
    const event = await this.repository.findOneBy({
      id: 3
    })
    Logger.log(event, 'lol');
    return event;
  }

  @Get(':id')
  async findOne(@Param('id') id) {
    const event = await this.repository.findOneBy({
      id: id
    })
    return event;
  }
```

It's working fine, now.